# Let's encrypt certification on a "new" domain

Tags: debian, certificate, apache2, subdomain, lets-encrypt

I used to host my website through squarespace at the name *domain.com*.

I've decided to go over to wordpress self-hosted.

I removed the CNAME DNS config with my provider.

I already have a phpBB forum at *forum.domain.com* which has been working well.

Now I tried to set up virtualhost through apache2. Create directories in /var/www/domain.com and then I tried to restart apache2, which failed.
(Through mkdir for the folders, and a2ensite after that)

```
systemctl | tails
```

Said the problem lies in my letsencrypt config

[image]

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        <IfDefine config_ssl>
            ServerAdmin ${config_serveradmin}
            ServerName ${config_servername}
            DocumentRoot /var/www/${config_servername}/public_html

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/${config_servername}/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/${config_servername}/privkey.pem
     </IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
```

More specifically in

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/${config_servername}/fullchain.pem
```

I checked the folders, but can't find any folder for *domain.com*. Only a folder for *forum.domain.com*

[image]

Full config for the site is

```
#
#  Domain Configuration
#

# Configuration
Define config_servername domain.com
Define config_serveralias domain.com
Define config_serveradmin admin@domain.com
Define config_ssl true

#
#
#

<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin ${config_serveradmin}
        ServerName  ${config_servername}
        ServerAlias ${config_serveralias}

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/${config_servername}/public_html

        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/${config_servername}/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>

        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /var/www/${config_servername}/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/${config_servername}/logs/access.log combined
        <IfDefine config_ssl>
          RewriteEngine on
          RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =${config_servername}
          RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
        </IfDefine>

</VirtualHost>

#
#   Enable .htaccess
#
<Directory "/var/www/${config_servername}/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>

#
# SSL Configuration
#

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        <IfDefine config_ssl>
            ServerAdmin ${config_serveradmin}
            ServerName ${config_servername}
            DocumentRoot /var/www/${config_servername}/public_html

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/${config_servername}/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/${config_servername}/privkey.pem
     </IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>

UnDefine config_serveradmin
UnDefine config_servername
UnDefine config_serveralias
UnDefine config_ssl
```

How can I fix let's encrypt?

Answer (score 0):

It worked restarting apache2 when I added a `#` to `Define config_ssl true`

```
#Define config_ssl true
```